# Tools for laptop software provisioning?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, provisioning

At our company, we receive a laptop that is mostly pre-configured for a new employee using their own software provisioning tool.  However, with our development teams, there tends to be a number of additional tools and settings that we need to set up on a computer before the employee can be "ready to go".  This differs on a team-by-team basis, so a common solution for all development teams is to get the computer and manually install/setup the missing pieces for that laptop.

Are there any personal software provisioning systems for Windows-based computers that would allow our team to be able to keep our own software up-to-date across our team?

I was thinking something that wouldn't be limited to new computer setups, but would allow a team to apply patch updates that would let them get the latest version of their dev environment set up so that the team can make assumptions about "it works on my system" meaning "it works on our common dev environment".

Answer (score 3):

Check out Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager.

Managing disconnected laptops is always more challenging that desktops in an office, but SCCM (and other management apps) offers a number of approaches to manage disconnected workstations. If you're willing to setup a PKI, you'll be able to apply software updates and securely manage your laptops via any internet connection.